# Can the operation of the user-implemented atomic by assemble establish a synchronous relationship?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, atomic

Consider a user-implemented atomic object, and the following code is pseudo-code:

```cpp
struct SpinLock{
   bool* ptr
   void lock(){
      // mov eax, false
      // new_val = true
      while /* lock cmpxchg [ptr], new_val */{  // until *ptr == false
      }
   }
   void unlock(){
     // mov [ptr], false
   }
};
```

Assume this `SpinLock` infrastructure is used in multi-threads, however, [atomics.order] p2 says:

> An atomic operation A **that performs a release operation** on an atomic object M **synchronizes with an atomic operation B that performs an acquire operation** on M and takes its value from any side effect in the release sequence headed by A.

In this user-implemented atomic object, we cannot have release and acquire operations because they are compiler tags, in my opinion. So, that means, the prior `unlock` in a thread cannot establish a happen-before relationship with the lastest `lock` in another thread.

So, I wonder, is this true that we cannot implement our `spinlock` with a user-implemented atomic object? Even more, we cannot implement our `ordering_acquire` and `ordering_release` because the compiler won't recognize them. `std::ordering_acquire` and `std::ordering_release` are special citizens for the compiler.

Comment: Assembly language interop is not covered by the C++ language standard.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, inline assembly is entirely implementation-defined. The standard says nothing about what kind of effect inline assembly could have on the abstract machine.

This is largely because you're operating at two levels of abstraction:

- High level concepts like "synchronizes with" ultimately describe what assembly (including fences) a compiler may emit. (For example, modifying an object can be seen as a formalization of a `mov` instruction)
- Based on what (inline) assembly you have, it can be reasoned what behavior emerges for the abstract machine. (For example, a `mov` instruction can be seen as modifying an object in the C++ sense)

In your case, `lock cmpxchg` is an instruction which could have been emitted by any `compare_exchange` function on x86_64. You could reason backwards from that that it should be equivalent to a `compare_exchange_strong` with `std::memory_order::seq_cst`.

However, this reasoning is informal and nothing in the standard requires it. You have to consult your compiler's manual. [GCC inline assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) requires you to specify what memory gets clobbered to prevent unwanted optimizations.

Comment: [intro.races#21](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#21) says non-atomic data-race-free access should obey "happen before", which is strictly defined in [intro.races] p10, that means, two evaluations `A` and `B` in different threads should satisfy that `A` synchronize with `B`, the standard defines which operations are synchronized. Unless the compiler says which ASM code can establish "synchronous", it doesn't give any implementation-defined room to specify a "happens before" relationship.

Comment: @xmh0511 sure, but who is to say that from a compiler's standpoint, inline assembly with a `lock` prefix doesn't follow a "happens before" relation in the abstract machine sense? Furthermore, if it is UB, that just means that there is no restriction on what an implementation can do. At that point you have to reason about what kind of effect an inline assembly may have, since the standard doesn't say anything, and you have to rely on the implementation respecting your intent.

Answer (score 0):

If what you implement by hand gives sufficient ordering on the target platform, then you can consider it as creating a syncs-with.  e.g. it a hand-written asm implementation of `pthread_mutex_lock` could well be what a C++ implementation ultimately uses for `std::mutex` to provide the locking with `acquire` semantics required by the ISO C++ standard.

If you do that for your own functions, then yes you can still reason about your program in terms of syncs-with / happens-before as long as you get the asm details correct to give all the necessary guarantees on the target ISA.  As if you'd used `std::atomic` to get the compiler to emit similar asm.

The C++ standard doesn't say anything about hand-written asm functions.  If your asm interacts with any C++ objects, it's up to you to make the interaction ABI-compatible with the compiler.  (Including for `std::atomic`, using a compatible [mapping from C++ ordering to asm](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Epes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html), and for non-lock-free atomics, respecting the same lock.)

Comment: However, I cannot give that "sufficient ordering" because `std::ordering` not only affects the emitted asm code but also affects the code reordering. Moreover, [intro.races#21](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#21) explicitly specifies data-race-free access that is not atomic(in terms of standard) should obey "happen before", it didn't give any implementation-defined room.

Comment: @xmh0511: If your pseudo-code is for non-inline asm (in a separate `.asm` or `.S` file), no compile-time reordering across it is possible except for private local vars.  It's a black-box for the optimizer that might modify any globally-reachable memory. ([How does a mutex lock and unlock functions prevents CPU reordering?](//stackoverflow.com/q/50951011) / [Is function call an effective memory barrier?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10698253))   Or if this is GNU C inline asm, you should use a `"memory"` clobber to give the asm statement the same might-read-and/or-write-everything semantics.

Comment: @xmh0511: If you do it correctly, non-atomic accesses will be ordered by your asm (at compile-time and run-time), as well as `std::atomic` accesses.  In that case, you can talk about it and reason about it the same way you would for code that used `std::atomic` to do the same thing.  If not, you can't, depending on exactly what ordering bugs exist in your asm and/or the way you told the compiler about your asm.

Comment: I think, regardless of non-inline or inline assembly, in both cases, we cannot establish "happen before" in terms of the definition in [intro.races] p10. There is no wording that can specify the hand write `lock` will synchronize with the `unlock` even though we do everything correctly here.

Comment: @xmh0511: You can treat `lock cmpxchg` as a `compare_exchange_strong(..., seq_cst)` and `mov` as `.store(val, release)`, because the C++ to asm mapping for x86-64 that compilers actually use (https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html) would translate those things to that asm.

Comment: @xmh0511: Or equally valid reasoning is that the x86 memory model guarantees that code after a `lock cmpxchg` which sees a value from a `mov` store will also see all previous loads/stores from before the `mov`.  The x86 memory model guarantees are as strong as C++ happens-before, so you can treat your asm as giving you a C++ happens-before.  Of course the C++ standard doesn't say anything about this; assembly language isn't part of the ISO C++ standard at all, so it's already an extension.  Thus the semantics are defined by the implementation.

Comment: I just feel like this question like that we cannot implement our `memcpy` in the standard C++.

Comment: @xmh0511: Huh?  What are you talking about with `memcpy`?

Comment: I meant, from a C++ standard perspective, user-implemented `memcpy` is UB but implementations may guarantee that the user-implemented `memcpy` does what the user wants to do. The `synchronous` issue is just like this case.